# mongodb aggregation optimization: $sort and $group

Tags: mongodb, query-optimization, nosql-aggregation

For simple, I have a document like this:

| name | weight_1 | weight_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| aaaa | 1 | 5 |
| bbbb | 4 | 4 |
| cccc | 2 | 3 |
| bbbb | 3 | 2 |
| cccc | 5 | 1 |

My goal is to output a list and sort by `weight_2` `asc`. If there are more than 1 records for each `name`, pick the smallest `weight_1`, so the result will be unique in `name`.

what I have done:
Step 1. group by `name`, select grouped result by first record from `weight_1` `asc`, it becomes

| name | weight_1 | weight_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| aaaa | 1 | 5 |
| bbbb | 3 | 2 |
| cccc | 2 | 3 |

Step 2. sort result from 1. by `weight_2` `asc`, and it is my expected output:

| name | weight_1 | weight_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| bbbb | 3 | 2 |
| cccc | 2 | 3 |
| aaaa | 1 | 5 |

So I use the following mongodb aggregation pipeline:

```
[
  {
    $sort: { weight_1: 1 }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: '$name',
      weight_1: { $first: '$weight_1' },
      weight_2: { $first: '$weight_2' }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: { weight_2: 1 }
  }
]
```

which is working, but since the second `$sort` will not able to use any index, how can I improve performance for this scenario?

Comment: You haven't described your indexes yet.  That would be helpful.  Why are you sorting before grouping?  That doesn't really make sense to me.  The final output is sorted by weight_2.  What is your goal/objective/requirement for sorting? In the post under the section "what i want..." you have objective 1, you skip objective 2, then you have objective 3.  Very confusing question.  Perhaps if you provide example data of how you would like the results, that would be helpful.

Comment: @barrypicker sorry for confusing, there are some typos. I have updated the question, and with my high level goal.

Comment: I'm sorry, I am still confused.  You show two different possible outputs.  Are you saying you want to define two queries and want to know what the indexes should be?

Comment: Is there a performance issue, and if so what is it? Is your query taking a lot of time?

Comment: @barrypicker there is only one expected output, it is the table below step 2. And my query is working, but a `$sort` after `$group` will not able to use any index, though I can add index `{ weight_1: 1 }` for step 1. I am looking for better if it can.

Comment: @prasad_ currently data size is small, it is still not very long but I can see when data grow, it will be a serious concern to sort full document without indexing in step 2.

Comment: your requirements are still vague.  If I have two records nearly identical - `{name: "aaaa", weight_1: 1, weight_2: 1}, name: "aaaa", weight_1: 1, weight_2: 2}`, you say you want the minimum weight_1 values, but in these two records have the same weight_1 value, so the question moves to weight_2 - which weight_2 do you want?  Is it arbitrary?  Any will do, or do you want the minimum weight_2 also, then sort by weight_2?